# Show text after a specific character

Tags: bash

I need to write bash script that input an ip address,
then show just the number that come after slash

for example if I enter 192.168.1.0/24
I want to catch just "24"

I tried to do this:

```
read ip 
echo $ip | cut -c 13-14
```

its working fine just with this ip.

what about if I have

> 192.168.100.100/24

the place of slash will change,
so im wondering if there is any idea how to catch charachter that come after slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `cut`, you can specify the delimiter and the fields

```
echo "192.168.1.0/24" | cut -d/ -f2
24
```

**What it does?**

- `-d/` specifies the delimiter as `/`.
- `-f2` chooses the second field.

---

**Solution using `awk`**

```
$ echo "192.168.1.0/24" | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
24
```